# Google cloud VPN error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

I am trying to connect my Google Cloud VPC to a secure network via a VPN.

I am unable to connect and log shows the following:

```
D  generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ] 
D  no matching peer config found 
D  looking for peer configs matching YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY[%any]...XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[192.168.0.2] 
D  parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) AUTH SA TSi TSr ] 
D  received packet: from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[4500] to YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY[4500] (204 bytes) 
D  sending packet: from YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY[500] to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[500] (440 bytes) 
D  generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(MULT_AUTH) ] 
D  remote host is behind NAT 
I  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is initiating an IKE_SA
```

What am I missing? The peer network gateway IP is configured as XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and my Google Cloud IP is YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY.

The steps to create the VPN followed are mentioned in the following link:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns#creating_a_gateway_and_a_tunnel_for_an_auto_mode_vpc_network_using_only_the_gateway_subnet

What could be wrong?

All the configuration are as per the settings mentioned in the document:
https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithFortinetFortiGate300C.pdf

Comment: It seems it is because google cloud platform VPN doesn't support NAT Traversal.

Comment: 1:1 NAT is supported by Google cloud VPN. The logs you attached doesn't enough time understand what's the problem

Comment: NAT-Traveral wasn't supported. Had checked with Google Support.

Comment: @sanjay If [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48545195/291796) was correct, please **both** upvote **and** accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have NAT-T enabled; <strike>unfortunately, it's [not supported](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpns#set_up_the_peer_vpn_gateway)</strike>.

*EDIT 2019-03-14:* NAT-T is now supported with the [correct configuration](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/troubleshooting#gateways_behind_nat).

Answer (score -1):

`generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]`

You have an authentication problem.

Usually this problem is due to a misconfigured pre-shared key.
Have you double checked it?